# vba key pause/resume - toggle

Tags: excel, vba

if the code - GetAsyncKeyState replaced with MsgBox, it's working fine however though there is no error, code doesn't work with GetAsyncKeyState.

or can command/toggle button will work with EXCEL VBA?

```
#If VBA7 Then
    'declare virtual key event listener
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    'declare virtual key event listener
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#End If
Private Const VK_RA = &H27

Sub Hide_Next()

    Dim a           As Range
    Dim b           As Range

        Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("a").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyRight) Then
            Application.Goto Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True

            For Each a In Range("A2:A23").Cells
                If a.Value = Empty Then
                    a.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next a
        End If

        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyRight) Then
            Columns("b").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            For Each b In Range("B2:B23").Cells
                If b.Value <> Empty Then
                    b.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            Next b

        End If

        If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RA) Then
            Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

Working Code, trying to replace MagBox with Keypress:
Sub Hide_Next()

```
Dim a           As Range
Dim b           As Range

        Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("a").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    MsgBox "Pause-A"
        Application.Goto Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True

        For Each a In Range("A2:A23").Cells
            If a.Value = Empty Then
                a.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next a

    MsgBox "Pause-B"
        Columns("b").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        For Each b In Range("B2:B23").Cells
            If b.Value <> Empty Then
                b.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next b

    'and so on for the next column ...

End Sub
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean. What value to get back in that msgbox when it's swapped out?

Comment: Using MsgBox, the script pauses with pop-up and continues when pressing the OK button,  instead of pop-up messagebox, trying to replace it with a keyboard event. for this case right arrow key.

Answer (score 0):

There's some strange things happening in your code.

1. The way this is written is that you would have to be pressing the right arrow key at the exact moment this subroutine is run. That's not preposterous or anything, but you don't state in your question what your expectation of this code is.
2. You check 3 times if that right key is being pressed and between each check you do some very slow front/ui actions like hiding rows and unhiding columns. If the user takes their finger off the right arrow key while excel is bopping around making changes the next block will not execute.
3. You check to see if the right arrow is pressed using both `vbKeyRight` and `VK_RA` constant. I'm not expert here but it DOES seem like both of those should return `&H27`... I would stick to one or the other though for debugging.

Rewriting:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    'declare virtual key event listener
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    'declare virtual key event listener
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#End If
Private Const VK_RA = &H27

Sub Hide_Next()

    Dim a As Range      
    Dim rightKeyDown As Boolean

    'Check if the right arrow key is being pressed before interacting with excel's slow UI. 
    If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RA) Then
        rightKeyDown = True
    End If

    'hide all the columns, except column A before doing anything
    Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("a").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    'Let's see if that right key was down
    If rightKeyDown Then        
        Application.Goto Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True
        For Each a In Range("A2:A23").Cells
            If a.Value = "" AND a.Offset(,1).Value = "" Then
                a.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next a
        Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

You also ask about a toggle button. It's not clear what your intentions are though (what is being toggled amongst these multiple steps?). A toggle button is an option though.

Comment: Let me update the thread with a simple example, the basic idea is to load 1st column without empty cells, wait for a key press, load 1st, and 2nd column without empty cells, wait for a key press event and load 1st, 2nd, 3rd column wihout empty cells,...and so on...